# Vlookup in python with 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the df's below:

```
d1 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'ref': ['apple','orange','banana']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'apple': [1,2,3], 'orange': [4,5,6], 'banana':[7,8,9]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Need help. What I would like to do is create a new column in df1 that populates the values from df2 for each ref by id

Comment: IIUC, the new column values would be `[1, 5, 9]`, right?

Comment: Yes that would be the result. Apologies for not posting the output. Can do that now if needed

Comment: Yes, add it to the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `melt` then `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2.melt('id',var_name='ref'),how='left')
Out[72]: 
  id     ref  value
0  a   apple      1
1  b  orange      5
2  c  banana      9
```

More like `vlookup`

```
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
df1['new'] = df2.values[df2.index.get_indexer(df1.id),df2.columns.get_indexer(df1.ref) ]
df1
Out[76]: 
  id     ref  new
0  a   apple    1
1  b  orange    5
2  c  banana    9
```